# как настроить padding, и сделать углы закругленными

Tags: java, android, xml

Почему не работает классический android:padding="10dp" в LinearLayout, который находится в ScrollView.

[image: пример]

Сам код -

```
<ConstrainLayout
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="649dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.024">
    
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    
    
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/oneworkspace"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@color/workspace"
                    android:padding="10dp"
    
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        </ScrollView>
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как сделать углы компонента View скругленными ?

Comment: создать shape Drawable в xml и сделать его фоном

Comment: ConstraintLayout довольно "тяжелый" контейнер, ставить его для одного виджета напрасное расточительство ресурсов, тем более, что ScrollView сам может быть контейнером